# Refactoring code in C++

Tags: c++, refactoring, gpx

The constructor function for the class route originally contained the following code that checks if an element ("gpx", "rte", etc) exists within a file. Which runs as it should.

```
  if (! elementExists(source,"gpx"))
  {
      oss << endl << "no gpx tag";
      constructorReport = oss.str();
      constructorSucceeded = false;
      return;
  }
  if (! elementExists(source,"rte"))
  {
      oss << endl << "no rte tag";
      constructorReport = oss.str();
      constructorSucceeded = false;
      return;
  }
```

I've tried to introduce a function to replace these if statements. The program builds okay.

```
void Route::constCheck(string source, string type)
{

    if (! XML_Parser::elementExists(source, type))
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << std::endl << "no" << type <<" tag";
        constructorReport = oss.str();
        constructorSucceeded = false;
        return;
    }
}
```

I've changed the gpx file which it checks to produce an error but with my added function it continues as if there is no error.

Any help is appreciated and please let me know if you need more info. I tried to keep the code light per guidelines.

Comment: What do you think `return` does?

Comment: return for void functions are not necessary :) But the problem here lies elsewhere.

Comment: Can you show us how and where you're executing your new function?

Comment: In your modified function you are not printing to `oss` the same thing: there's no space after "no" (unless `type` begins with a space, which I doubt). No idea whether this is the issue, it really depends on what you do with it, but it could be.

Comment: I've tried to return pair x<string, bool>. Then set the value of constructorReport = x.first and constructorSucceeded = x.second.

Comment: User I cannot post large segments of code in this chat. But I'm calling the function like so in the constructor for route. route is then constructed in the main function.
      constCheck(source, "gpx");
      constCheck(source, "rte");

I'm not sure how to be more specific.

Comment: @user54264611634646244 **return** is the problem. Kerrek hits the nail on the head! But perhaps it would have been clearer to ask: "What do you think **return** _did in the original code_?"

Comment: @JohnDoe Don't use comments to clarify your question. Use the [edit] link.

Comment: The problem has been solved using the code posted by Barmar. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original code, you return from the function the first time one of the tests fails, you don't continue trying the other tests.

Now that you've moved the test into a function, there's no way for the caller to know if the test fails, so it will perform all of them, and never return from its function when one of them fails. You need this function to return a boolean that indicates whether it failed.

```
bool Route::constCheck(string source, string type)
{

    if (! XML_Parser::elementExists(source, type))
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << std::endl << "no" << type <<" tag";
        constructorReport = oss.str();
        constructorSucceeded = false;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then the replacement for your original code would look like:

```
if (!constCheck(source, "gpx")) {
    return;
}
if (!constCheck(source, "rte")) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: I understand where I was going wrong. The code worked perfectly I just had to omit the ! when calling it. Thanks for the help!.